# Invalid python interpreter selected for the project - Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv, pythoninterpreter

I encountered an error in one of my projects after a few months, and it wasn't there the last time I checked. I previously fixed a similar error in another project by deleting the virtual environment (venv) folder and adding the same interpreter again.
[image: Actual error display message]
However, this solution isn't working now. Has anyone experienced this before and can provide assistance? My friend also faced a similar problem, and we are both struggling to find a solution. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

I've attempted to resolve it by referring to numerous answers from various sources, but the issue persists.

Comment: The issue has been resolved after I deleted the .idea folder along with venv folder, though I exactly don't know how it happened.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this issue is the same as the one I've experienced before, but if so here is my solution that always works for me.

Firstly, definitely try installing that package that its prompting you with.
But secondly if you go to 'configure python interpreter' and press 'make available to all projects', this always works for me.
[Picture of the pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALAk1.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).